# Understanding why TPL Task can update UI withOUT FromCurrentSynchronizationContext

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, events, mvvm

I am doing some TPL in VS2012, WPF with MVVM.  I have a question that I think I know the answer to but wanted to know for sure.  Consider this snippet:

```
TaskCanceller = new CancellationTokenSource();
TaskLoader = Task<object>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    //Test the current query
    DataRepository dr = new DataRepository(DataMappingSelected);
    string test = dr.TestMappingConnection();
    if (test.IsNotNullEmpty())
        throw new DataConnectionException(test);

    //Create the CSV File
    DataQueryCsvFile CsvFile = new DataQueryCsvFile();
    CsvFile.FileName = IO.Path.GetFileName(FilePath);
    CsvFile.FilePath = IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(FilePath);

    CsvFile.DataMapping = DataMappingSelected;
    CsvFile.DataBrowserQuery = DataQueryHolder;

    //Allow for updates to the UI
    CsvFile.PageExportComplete += (s, e) =>
    {
        if (TaskCanceller.IsCancellationRequested)
            (s as DataQueryCsvFile).IsSaveCancellationRequested = true;

        StatusData = String.Format("{0} of {1} Complete", e.ProgressCount, e.TotalCount);
        StatusProgress = (100 * e.ProgressCount / e.TotalCount);
    };

    CsvFile.SaveFile();

    return CsvFile;
});
```

I have a class DataQueryCsvFile.  Its intent is to create a CSV text file based off a passed set of query parameters the results of which can be very large.  So the export "paginates" the table produced by the query so it does not blow the users memory.  Among its members is an Event called PageExportComplete which is called whenever a "Page" is written to a file - say 1000 records at a time.  The code below uses this event to update a progress indicator on the UI.

The progress indicators (StatusData and StatusProgress) are declared in the VM with appropriate Notification to let the View know when they are changed.  For example:

```
public string StatusData
{
    get { return _StatusData; }
    set { NotifySetProperty(ref _StatusData, value, () => StatusData); }
}
private string _StatusData;
```

Here is my question - as is, this works very well.  But why since I did NOT declare the Task to run or update via the UI thread (FromCurrentSynchronizationContext) in a ContinueWith.

Is it because the MVVM pattern?  In other words, because the properties being updated are local to the VM and because they have the notification to update the View and because of the lose coupling via bindings its works?  Or am I just lucky due to the circumstances and I should go through the trouble of declaring a ContinueWith to update progress on the UI thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UI related stuff can only be updated from UI thread` whereas any CLR property binded to UI can be updated from background thread, they don't have thread affinity issue.

Like you posted in your sample, `you are only updating View model properties from background thread which is perfectly fine` but if you `try updating Progress bar text directly, it will fall miserably` since progressBar is UI component and can only be updated from UI thread.

---

Say you have `TextBlock` binded to `Name` property in ViewModel class:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="txt" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
```

If you try to update text directly, you will get famous thread affinity issue:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => txt.Text = "From background");
```

But in case you try to update ViewModel Name property, it will work fine since no UI stuff is access from background thread here:

```
ViewModelClass vm = DataContext as ViewModelClass;
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => vm.Name = "From background");
```

Comment: Thanks Rohit.  So it seems the key for this all to work is, in fact, the Bindings.  By design it is a lose connection so does that mean they are technically running on separate threads and by some magic you avoid the whole cross-threading problem?

Comment: Key to binding refresh is property change event which we achieve using `INPC`. Binding engine internally listen on that event and might be possible that marshall updating UI objects on UI dispatcher. Hence avoiding any cross-thread problem.